# Maxima of a function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

**Question:**

> If $$f(x) = \cos\frac{\pi x}{2015};     x>0$$ and $$f(x) = 2x + a; x\leq 0$$
>   Find the values of $a$ such that $x = 0$ is a point of local maxima for $f(x)$

**Attempt:**

As it's a point of local maxima, there are two conditions which have to be fulfilled:

1. The function has to be continuous at $x = 0$
2. The derivative of the function at $x = 0$ has to be equal to zero

Upon solving for the above two conditions, I only get a single value of $a$. However, the answers that are given are:

1. $a \geq 0$
2. $a \leq 0$
3. $a \geq 1$
4. $a \leq 1$

What is the fault in my logic? How can I get a range for the values of $a$ if the function is only continuous for one value of $a$?

Comment: How can f be both of those functions?

Comment: @nitin Very sorry, it was a typo. All corrected now. Thanks for pointing it out. :D

Comment: A function does not need to be differentiable at a local maximum.

Comment: @JohnMcGee Ahaa....... Very strange I say. How exactly is that possible? And if it is... what should be my approach to solving such a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x=0$ to be the coordinate of the local maximum, there must exist a neighborhood of 0 such that $f(0)$ is the maximum. Since cosine attains 1 when $x=0$, a sufficiently small right neighborhood of 0 has values strictly less than 1. The left neighborhood has values less than $a$ because $2x + a$ is increasing. Thus $a$ is a maximum if and only if it is greater than values on the right neighborhood. Hence $a \geq 1$.

Comment: Had you up to the last sentence... Can't really understand why we need $a \geq 1$

Comment: Does the edit help? It would be in your best interest to draw a graph of f (just a rough sketch) and see what I mean by neighborhood of 0

Comment: I get that part. I get how the values are less than $a$ in the neighborhood of $x = 0$. However, for there to be a maxima at $x = 0$ wouldn't we want that the left neighborhood always be less than 1?

Comment: The left neighborhood *is* less than one. 2x + a is an increasing function.

Answer (score 1):

The standard definition of a local maxima of $f$ at $x_0$ is that you have an open set $U$ with $x_0 \in U$ and $f(x) \le f(x_0)$ for $x \in U$.
Nothing required on function continuity or differentiability.

For $x > 0$ $f(x) \le 1$ and $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = 1$$ Hence we must have $f(0) = a \ge 1$. This condition is also sufficient as $f$ is increasing on $(-\infty, 0)$ whatever the value of $a$ is.

**Conclusion: $f$ has a local maxima at $0$ if and only if $a \ge 1$.**

Comment: Happy that I somehow ticked the correct option on the test. However, what I'm confused on is the fact that if 1 is the maximum value of $f(x)$, then if we have $a = 2$ for example, won't the left neighborhood of the function have a greater value than 1?

Comment: No such a risk. $f$ is increasing on the left of $0$. So the maximum is reached on $(-\infty, 0)$ at $0$.

Comment: Hmmm... Still not completely clear. Still waiting for that 'Eureka!' moment.

Comment: Can you precise what statement is unclear for you?

Comment: Oh never mind. I got it. Yes it all makes sense now :)